# c++ templates: avoiding zero-length arrays without taking up extra space

Tags: c++, templates

### Note:

The answer to this question works, according to [liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3PdFq$0), for recent versions of g++ (4.7.2), clang (3.2), and icc (13.0.1), but per Stephen Lin's remarks it depends on [empty base optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization) and the implementation of `std::tuple`.

---

### The original question:

If I have a template struct that looks like this:

```
template<
    class T1, unsigned short N1,
    class T2, unsigned short N2
>
struct ComboThree {
    T1 data_1[N1];
    T2 data_2[N2];
};
```

I can avoid zero-length arrays and extra alignment padding by specializing it:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct ComboThree<T1, 0, T2, 0> {
};

template<class T1, class T2, unsigned short N2>
struct ComboThree<T1, 0, T2, N2>
{
    T2 data_2[N2];
};

template<class T1, unsigned short N1, class T2>
struct ComboThree<T1, N1, T2, 0>
{
    T1 data_1[N1];
};
```

But specializing like this becomes something of a hassle when the X of the TX/NX pairs gets much bigger.  In my project, the actual number of different combinations is probably going to be fewer than five, so I may end up not using templates at all, but I was curious:

**Is there a way to use TEMPLATE MAGIC to avoid zero-length arrays while avoiding taking up any extra space?**

For example, this:

```
template<class T, unsigned short N>
struct Array {
    T data[N];
};

template<class T>
struct Array<T, 0> {};

template<
    class T1, unsigned short N1,
    class T2, unsigned short N2
>
struct ComboTwo {
    Array<T1, N1> data_1;
    Array<T2, N2> data_2;
};
```

avoids the zero-length arrays, but the empty structs take up extra space.  On the other hand, this:

```
template<class T, unsigned short N>
struct Array {
    T data[N];
};

template<class T>
struct Array<T, 0> {};

template<
    class T1, unsigned short N1,
    class T2, unsigned short N2
>
struct ComboFour : Array<T1, N1>, Array<T2, N2> {};
```

seems to do what I want (does it?), but I have no idea how to access the data in the Array<> base structs in my program.  [It also has other limitations noted by Stephen Lin below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15183353/1502548)

Comment: Note that the `Array<T, 0>` subobjects of `ComboFour` may or may not take zero space, this is called `Empty base optimization` and is allowed, but not required, by the standard.

Comment: For $100 you can buy 8 GB of RAM. That's the alternate solution to this problem.

Comment: @BoPersson it may or may not be premature optimization in this case, but wasted space from empty subobjects does add up; otherwise library writers wouldn't spend so much effort on EBO

Comment: @Stephen - I was thinking return on investment. Quite a few questions on SO is about saving a nanosecond or a few bytes. Can we afford doing that?

Comment: @BoPersson - I was considering using something along these lines to store the position/normal/etc. data of a single vertex in a 3d model, if that helps explain my space concerns at all.

Comment: @BoPersson Well, you only have to code a generic solution up once, and you get to reap the benefits forever; that's pretty much the C++ philosophy. So it all depends on how much this is going to be reused and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer but it's too hard to fit in a comment. To access the subobjects of `ComboFour`, if you really wanted to do the last option, would require the following ugly syntax:

```
ComboFour<int, 2, float, 1> cf;
cf.Array<int, 2>::data[0] = 0;
cf.Array<int, 2>::data[1] = 1;
cf.Array<float, 1>::data[0] = 2.0f;
```

You could probably clean this up with some accessor functions but it still wouldn't be great.

The bigger problem, though, is that the following is an error:

```
ComboFour<int, 1, int, 1> cf2 // fails to compile
```

because the same class cannot be used as a parent twice.

(Also, note, `Array<T, 0>` subobjects of `ComboFour` may or may not take zero space, this is called "empty base optimization" and is allowed, but not required, by the standard.)

There is probably some way to get around the second problem...I think inheriting from `std::tuple<...>` (which may or may not be implemented using empty base optimization internally by your standard library implementation) of `Array<T, N>`, is probably the easiest way to do this, if you really had to, but it would make the syntax even uglier.

**EDIT**: This works for me on GCC 4.7.2

```
template<
    class T1, unsigned short N1,
    class T2, unsigned short N2,
    class T3, unsigned short N3
>
struct Combo : std::tuple<Array<T1, N1>, Array<T2, N2>, Array<T3, N3>>
{
};
```

and later...

```
Combo<int, 2, int, 2, float, 3> c;
std::get<0>(c).data[0] = 0;
std::get<0>(c).data[1] = 1;
std::get<1>(c).data[0] = 2;
std::get<1>(c).data[1] = 3;
std::get<2>(c).data[0] = 0.0;
std::get<2>(c).data[1] = 1.0;
std::get<2>(c).data[2] = 2.0;

assert(sizeof(Combo<int, 0, int, 0, float, 1>) == sizeof(float));
```

(To be honest, the standard library more or less requires empty base optimization to be usable, so even though it's not required I'd be surprised if any recent compiler did not support it; whether or not `std::tuple<...>` in written to properly take advantage of this optimization is another matter.)

Comment: Thanks.  I just noticed "the bigger problem", too, and came back to note that in an edit.  Thanks also for teaching me the syntax.

Comment: You could probably use a macro to make the syntax less ugly, by the way, just don't tell anyone I said that (macros are evil :D)

Comment: @tecu, is this working for you on your compiler? the syntax is not that nice, obviously, but you can write some helper functions on `Combo` to help a bit.

Comment: It is for me, yes (pretty neat trick, too).  I take it from the last bit in your answer that std::tuple isn't guaranteed to behave this way by the standard?

Comment: @tecu, no it's not, it's purely up to the library implementation if they want to use this optimization, and also whether the compiler supports it.